# Read whole .SQL file and generate JSON format database tables, without using any database server

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb

I have specific .sql file to create new database and table, insert data.

I can parse the database and tables with MariaDB server and simple node.js application.

(Just read .sql file and run each SQL query in MariaDB server using mariadb NPM, and convert to JSON format)

```
// Example simple code I used
import mariadb from "mariadb"; // It use mariaDB server - I don't want to use DB server

const pool = mariadb.createPool({ host, user, password, connectionLimit: 10 });
const queries = readSQLFile('./sample_sql_file.sql'); // The SQL file include thousands SQL queries
const connection = pool.getConnection();

const dataJson = {}; // Result of database, JSON format

for(const query of queries) {
    await connection.query(query); // Execute each SQL line and save result in MariaDB database
}

const tables = (await connection.query(`show tables in ${PROJECT_DATABASE}`)).map(
    (e) => e[`Tables_in_${PROJECT_DATABASE}`]
);

for (const table of tables) {
    const data = await conn.query(`SELECT * FROM \`${table}\``);
    dataJson[table] = [...data];
}
```

But actually I want is that without MariaDB server.

How can I parse all SQL queries in .sql file and get all data without any database server?

```
// Example concept code I want
import VirtualDatabase from "somethimg"; // Actually I need it, it doesn't use any database server

const queries = readSQLFile('./sample_sql_file.sql'); // The SQL file include thousands SQL queries
const dataJson = {}; // Result of database, JSON format

const database = new VirtualDatabase();

for(const query of queries) {
    database.runQuery(query); // Run each query line, and generate database and tables
}

const tables = database.getTables(); // Gets all tables in database;

for (const table of tables) {
    const data = database.getData(table);
    dataJson[table] = [...data];
}
```

As-Is

1. Prepare .sql file
2. Create database into MariaDB using .sql file
3. Read database in MariaDB server using mariadb NPM module
4. Generate JSON format using the read database

To-Be

1. Prepare .sql file
2. Just read .sql file in Node.js
3. Parse the whole queries in .sql file
4. Generate JSON format using the read database

Comment: There exists an SQL parser implemented as a Node.js package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sql-parser but it is based on MySQL 5.7 grammar, not MariaDB. There are differences in the SQL implemented by MariaDB and MySQL, so this parser won't be a 100% accurate as a test of your SQL syntax if you need it to be compatible with MariaDB. I suppose you could use that package as a starting point and modify it to match the current MariaDB grammar.

Comment: Show us a sample of the .sql file; maybe the format issues are minor and a regexp could do the trick.

Comment: if there's nothing mariadb specific in your sql file and you want to make minimal changes to your code, you could use sqllite3 instead of mariadb, possibly with an in-memory database.

Comment: @BillKarwin I checed those kind of npm SQL parser (also I found node-sql-parser, supports mariadb) but as my understanding, the parser only "parse" the SQL query but not generate database JSON. So to use it for my purpose, I must implement my own database generator function using the npm module. Am I correct?

Comment: @RickJames .SQL contains the SQL queries: drop all tables if exists, and create many new tables and insert data to each table (Just create new tables and put data). Actually syntax/format related issue is not for me now. I need generator that generate JSON format data from the .sql file.

Comment: @ysth Actually I don't know about SQL query syntax, but the .sql file is from other database based on mariadb. So I cannot change database system.

Comment: I don't know of any tools that generate JSON. I think you'll have to take responsibility for that. JSON is a highly variable format, and you may have specific needs for it, so it's unlikely that any third-party tool will generate JSON in exactly the format you need.

Comment: if you are the one controlling generating the sql, mariadb-dump can take options to make dump less specific to mariadb.  in any case, dumps are essentially a bunch of creates and inserts; it's definitely worth trying if you can run your sql in sqlite3 as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use parser in node-sql-parser/build/mariadb npm and implement my own logic.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { Parser } = require("node-sql-parser/build/mariadb");
const parser = new Parser();

function parseLine(sqlFilePath) {
    const sqlFileStringLines = fs
        .readFileSync(sqlFilePath)
        .toString()
        .replaceAll(`\r\n`, `\n`)
        .split(`\n`);

    // To temporary parse query line, check just ';' character in data or real query end
    const END_OF_LINE_TOKEN = `$$$END_OF_LINE$$$`;
    const sqlValidQueries = sqlFileStringLines
        .filter((line) => line.indexOf(`/*`) === -1 && line.indexOf(`--`) === -1)
        .join(END_OF_LINE_TOKEN) // Stringify all values
        .split(`;${END_OF_LINE_TOKEN}`) // Only real each query will be splitted
        .map((e) => e.replaceAll(END_OF_LINE_TOKEN, ``)) // Remove temp token
        .map((e) => e.trim()) // Remove prefix blanks
        .filter((e) => e.length !== 0) // Uesless statement
        .map((e) => `${e};`); // Append `;` characters to all query to end of line

    return sqlValidQueries;
}

const parsedQueries = parseLine(`some_of_sql_file.sql`);

for (const line of parsedQueries) {
    const result = parser.parse(line);

    if (line.indexOf(`CREATE`) === 0) {
        // Do create table logic using parsed 'result' value

    } else if (line.indexOf(`INSERT`) === 0) {
        // Insert data to created table using parsed 'result' value
    }
    // .. Do more thing if needed
}
```